# Can a system be PERFECTLY simulated by a quantum (and classical) computer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, information, quantum-states

This is a thought experiment, and as such will assume some crazy things.

Let's say I decide to perfectly simulate my university as it is right now. I use a magic machine to instantly scan the entire campus for all the information I can access without affecting it (superpositions remain uncollapsed) and copy it into my computers.

I load the classical information into the classical computer, simple enough (in this thought experiment at least.)

Question 1: Now I try to scan and transfer all the quantum information. If my understanding of the no cloning theorem is correct, does that mean my only option would be to teleport the quantum states, destroying all the superpositions in my university? Would this essentially destroy the university?

Question 2: I now have all the information in my computers, so I decide to run the simulation. Could I run the simulation more than once? I believe this will depend on the no-cloning theorem and whether or not I will have enough information to recreate the starting conditions after the simulation has run.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm not sure that any of those questions directly address what I'm asking (if that's what you were implying.) I realize you didn't close this question, so maybe I just interpreted that incorrectly. If you just wanted to link some relevant information, I really appreciate it since I found something that'll be really useful for what I'm doing in one of those threads.

Comment: There are no magical machines in physics and science can't answer magical questions in general. What you want can't even be done for an entire atom, so why bother asking?

Comment: @CuriousOne This is a thought experiment that I'm using in order to check my understanding of the No Cloning Hypothesis and its relation to quantum computing. This isn't supposed to be a practical scenario, hence my first sentence.

Comment: Thought experiments that contradict observations are not even worth the thought. QC can't do anything that nature won't allow you to do, not even in theory.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You can only (repeatedly) simulate a system where you have perfect knowledge of the quantum state. If you don't have perfect knowledge of the quantum state, a "perfect" simulation in the sense you have in mind is not possible.

If the system is very small, you can try to projectively measure all quantum states. Then you have destroyed all superpositions, but you know the exact quantum state of the system after the measurement (in that you can write down the wave function after the measurement up to a global phase), which allows you to create a system in that same state, which can then be used as an input to your simulation. Note however that this will be extremely difficult to do in practice if the system has more than a couple of degrees of freedom.

Comment: And if you choose a particularly simple measurement basis, this will simplify the simulation a lot!  Just tear down the whole building, and the simulation becomes a piece of cake!

Comment: You never have perfect knowledge of the quantum state. You can prepare ONE state, which has nothing to do with the state of the system before the preparation. I thought we are teaching this in QM 101?

Comment: What I meant is the following: You can projectively measuere everything about your system (which effectively prepares ONE state which has nothing to do with the state before the measurement) and then you can clone that state as much as you like. I don't claim this is particularly useful...